# Android Mobile testing with Appium Selenium C#

Tags: android, visual-studio, selenium, testing, appium-android

I have tried a lot of different stuff from the google and you-tube and this is where i land and i cannot get it to work, my connection to the Appium and emulator is fine also i have checked the adb devices everything is fine.

I am getting error for the Line `driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));`

These are the two errors which i get:

> "cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumServiceBuilder'"

and

> "cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverOptions".

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Enums;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;

namespace UnitTestProject4
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver;
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 3a Pie 9.0 - API 28");
        cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");
        cap.SetCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
        cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp");
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but I would make a few small tweaks. Your error messages are complaining about two things -- the use of `DesiredCapabilities` instead of `AppiumOptions`, and the use of `new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub")` as a parameter for `AndroidDriver<IWebElement>`.

To solve these issues -- instead of `DesiredCapabilities`, I initialize my `AndroidDriver` with `AppiumOptions`. Additionally, you should try starting Appium through `AppiumServiceBuilder()` and use that service to start your driver session. You should also specify a parameter for `automationName`.

Here's what I always use to start a new mobile session on Android with C#:

```
// start appium service
var builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
var appiumLocalService = builder.UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
appiumLocalService.Start();

// create appium driver capabilities
var options = new AppiumOptions { PlatformName = "Android" };
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 3a Pie 9.0 - API 28");

// add app or appPackage / appActivity depending on preference
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp");

options.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2"); // this one is important

// these are optional, but I find them to be helpful -- see DesiredCapabilities Appium docs to learn more
options.AddAdditionalCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("allowSessionOverride", true);


// start the driver
var driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(appiumLocalService.ServiceUrl, options);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response, I went though the documentation and skipped most of it lol i guess i should have spent more time. It works for some reason it error-ed out there is no installed nodes even though i had appium and the nodes, fixed it by doing npm global install. its working much appreciated. I will look at you git hub as well. Thanks

Comment: I went through something similar when I first started working on this -- it took several days of research, trial and error, to finally get everything working. The most helpful resource I can direct you to is the official Appium repo, with C# code samples included: https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/sample-code/csharp

Comment: I have another question, How can i seprate the test cases while using this, also do i need to pass separate driver for each test case? D I need to follow setup and tear down process?

Comment: @Newbie Following SetUp and TearDown process is cleanest way to integrate this into your test cases. If you open another StackOverflow question (so this one does not go off topic), I would be happy to assist.

Comment: not sure what happened now it went up, i guess it will take sometime to get used to here

Comment: i really appreciate it from you :)